# Filter One Field to Exactly Match Multple Criteria (no "OR")

Tags: sql, ms-access

in the following table:

```
pk  buyorder    code    Person  Supplier    Product
1   1   code1   person1 Supplier1   pen
2   1   code1   person1 Supplier1   pencil
3   1   code1   person1 Supplier1   computer
4   2   code2   person1 Supplier1   phone
5   2   code2   person1 Supplier1   desk
6   2   code2   person1 Supplier1   chair
7   3   code2   person1 Supplier1   phone
8   3   code2   person1 Supplier1   toy
9   3   code2   person1 Supplier1   shoes
10  3   code2   person1 Supplier1   sneakers
11  4   code3   person2 Supplier2   phone
12  4   code3   person2 Supplier2   monitor
13  4   code3   person2 Supplier2   laptop
14  5   code4   person5 Supplier2   phone
15  5   code4   person5 Supplier2   suitcase
16  5   code4   person5 Supplier2   post-it
17  5   code4   person5 Supplier2   sneakers
18  6   code4   person4 Supplier2   phone
19  6   code4   person4 Supplier2   suitcase
20  6   code4   person4 Supplier2   wallet
21  6   code4   person4 Supplier2   chair
22  7   code4   person5 Supplier2   phone
23  7   code4   person5 Supplier2   suitcase
24  7   code4   person5 Supplier2   car
25  7   code4   person5 Supplier2   laptop
```

I would like to have a SQL Query that answers the following question: Who has Ordered a phone AND a suitcase AND a wallet AND a chair?

Update: I am using MS ACCESS which doesn't seem to support nested DISTINCT functions.

The answer I am looking for would be the one in BUYORDER=6, person4.

One of the helpful people (thanks so much btw) suggested that I use:

```
Select Person
from Table 
where product in ('phone','suitcase','wallet','chair')  
group by Person
having count( * ) = 4
```

However, this query is returning both person4 and person5 even though person5 does not have a buyorder that includes 'wallet' and 'chair'.

Thank you so much!

Special thanks to Blam for patiently spelling out the joins for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select A.person
from (SELECT DISTINCT person,product FROM yourtable) A
where A.product in ('phone','suitcase','wallet','chair')  
group by A.person 
having count(*) = 4
```

Comment: I am using MS ACCESS, it seems like it doesn't support the use of DISTINCT in that way... would you know an alternative way?

Comment: That query looks correct to me.  Did you try it, goobber?  If so, what happened?  Error message?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with the query but it is returning person4 and person5 eventhough person5 does not have a buyorder that contains 'wallet' and 'chair'...

Comment: Wait, I must have messed something up initially, it totally worked!!! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select person 
  from table 
 where product in ('phone','desk','char')  
 group by person 
having count(distinct(product)) = 3
```

you could also do it with an intersections or joins

```
select t1.*
  from table t1
  join table t2 
    on t2.person = t1.person 
   and t1.product = 'phone'
   and t2.product = 'desk'
  join table t3 
    on t3.person = t1.person
   and t3.product = 'char'
```

Comment: I am using MS ACCESS, it seems like it doesn't support the use of DISTINCT in that way... would you know an alternative way?

Comment: count(*) will work if you don't have duplicates.  I pointed out two alternatives in my answer.

Comment: I think it worked. Is there a way to see the other fields as well, like buyorder, supplier, product? When I try to include other fields on the SELECT statement, I get the message "supplier is not part of an aggregate function". Also, in case I have another buyorder that matches the criteria, would this query return both? And how would I do it with intersections or joins? Sorry, I'm new at SQL as you may have realized... thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: You can add other fields but you need to add them to the group by.  They need to be fields that don't change with the person or you break the group by.   I will spell out a join for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm still getting an error but I get your point. The first Query would be probably my best bet. When I use COUNT(*) instead of the nested DISTINCT, it seems to work. However, let's say that I want to filter by ('phone','suitcase','wallet','chair')  and change person3 to person5 (so now person5 is in buyorders 5 and 7), then the Query returns both, person4 and person5 even if buyorder 5 does not have "wallet", "chair"... any ideas?